# Affinity between Nodejitsu and IAAS

Tags: node.js, paas, nodejitsu, iaas, joyent

I'm evaluating Nodejitsu for hosting Node.JS.

I'm trying to understand the relationship between Nodejitsu and IAAS providers. In particular is Nodejitsu providing me the machines or can I choose that my machine will be on some specific cloud provider in some specific zone.

Here's my need: My node service will need to communicate with a separate machine which I will set up myself (due to heavy customization). I want this machine to be on the same data center of my Node servers so in/out network cost and latency are minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [nodejitsu FAQs](https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/faq/#where-are-personal-plan-drones-hosted), if you are on a personal plan, your host is Joyent's **us-east-1** datacenter in North Virginia (USA). Business plan users are able to [choose from additional datacenters](https://www.nodejitsu.com/paas/datacenters/) which include Joyent's **us-sw-1** in Las Vegas (USA), **eu-ams-1** in Amsterdam (Netherlands) or Telefónica's **eu-london-1** in London, England.

Looks like additional datacenters will include Joyent San Francisco (USA) and Telefónica in Madrid (Spain).

Update:

Nodejitsu recently experienced an extended outage which is [documented in detail on their blog](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/recent-instability-and-choosing-the-right-cloud). A consequence of this was to [drop support for Telefónica Instant Servers](https://www.nodejitsu.com/company/press/2013/09/10/drop-telefonica/).